# Create a lightbox/colorbox without adding a link before the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have downloaded colorbox plugin, linked the js file and css file. I make a call as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $(".colorbox").colorbox() 
});
```

However the particular plugin (and almost all the lightbox plugins I have checked!) require a link before the image. my issue is that I do not want to add a link to the image in order to trigger the lightbox. Is there a way I can add the .colorbox to images only??

Thank you.

Comment: You can call `.colourbox()` after the page has loaded, if required. Under what event do you need to do this?

Comment: Thanks. I believe I call it after the page has loaded. I have random small images within the website and what I require is when the user clicks the image, a pop up window to be appear with the image, if that make sense. Basically it is a lightbox plugin..but I do not want to include a link as all the plugins require.